# Alter table script in SQL Server database project

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

My Requirement is to create delta scripts for an existing project, so we will be making lot of changes and create more tables in it.

We have Dev, QA, Stage and Production environments. I want to do the changes only in dev environment and rest of the environments have to be taken care by Dacpac automatically using VSTS. All the scripts have to be re-runnable except the seed data.

I am able to add a table, but unable to add an `alter table` statement in database project in build mode. I don't want to import full database. Can the Dacpac not accept alter statements?

Since I have to check `if exists` for post deployment script, I don't want use `alter` statement there. How can I achieve this?

Comment: hey baskar, as in the other question you don't need ssdt for what you are doing. don't use ssdt - just write scripts and run them (you can use a tool if you want)

Answer (score 6):

I think you may have miss understood what the SQL Server database project is/does. The project it self uses SQL scripts to build an in memory model of what your database looks like. This model then compiles down to a DACPAC which contains meta data that describes what the database *should* look like. When you deploy the DACPAC, this generates a change script that will transform the database into a state that matches the model described in the DACPAC.

The reason your `ALTER TABLE` doesn't work is due to there being no table to alter. The project isn't a database and it doesn't know how to represent in memory your `ALTER` statements. If you include it in a pre or post deploy script, the model will ignore this. It will, as you found out, mess with the deployments to the other environments.

The ideal way to deploy your database to your `dev` environment is using VSTS via CI/CD practices with the DACPAC. I'm not sure why you don't want to use a DACPAC to deploy to your `dev` environment, but if this is a hard fast rule, then you can use schema compare in Visual Studio's SSDT to copy your changes locally to the target database.

Comment: I want to use DACPAC only to deploy all environment. We can create DACPAC only in SSDT right, Do we have any other way to create DACPAC file?

Comment: @BaskarManoharan You can use `SqlPackage` to create a DACPAC file. SSDT is just a tool in Visual Studio that allows us to create DACPAC as part of a build. If you have SSDT installed on your build server (comes by default with VS 2017) then you can use MSBuild to create the DACPAC and deploy it in your CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: You can create dacpacs from SSMS also. However it will fail if you have references to other databases, SqlPackage will help in that case